# QGIS Plugins - How to make sure that Vector and Raster layers in a folder are loaded only once?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt5

**Plugin Intro:**

I am creating a plugin for in-house development which lists the location of vector/raster layers of specific projects. Each project has a number of files ranging from 0 to few hundreds. The preface of the plugin is, I need to type the project ID and click a button which fetches the list of files (from an in-house database) in the form of table widget. When I click a specific row and click another button the files from the row clicked are opened in QGIS.

**Problem:**

When the number of files is one, the plugin works perfectly. The problem arises when the number of files are more than one. In the latter case when I click a row the same file is loaded several times. There is no loop in my code so I don't understand why this is happening. The code is pasted below.

Function to retrieve data and show in table widget:

```
def ListPage(self):
    self.tableWidget.clear() 
    self.cid = self.textEdit.toPlainText() #to get the number of project id #
    self.data = prj.getProductsByStatusAndOutput(status='READY_TO_CLOUDMASK', output_id=self.cid)
    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels (('Id','File Name','Status', 'Location'))
    header = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader()       
    header.setSectionResizeMode(0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
    header.setSectionResizeMode(1, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
    header.setSectionResizeMode(2, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
    header.setSectionResizeMode(3, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)



    for rowIndex, record in enumerate(self.data):
        itemId = QTableWidgetItem(record['identifier'])
        itemStatus = QTableWidgetItem(record['status'])
        itemFilename = QTableWidgetItem(record['filename'])
        itemloc = QTableWidgetItem(record['prod_location'])

        self.tableWidget.setItem( rowIndex, 0, itemId)
        self.tableWidget.setItem( rowIndex, 1, itemFilename)  
        self.tableWidget.setItem( rowIndex, 2, itemStatus)  
        self.tableWidget.setItem( rowIndex, 3, itemloc)

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.OpenQgis)
```

Function to open the files when a row is clicked:

```
def OpenQgis(self):


    row = self.tableWidget.currentRow()
    path = (self.tableWidget.item(row,3).text())
    sname = (self.tableWidget.item(row,1).text())
    vlocation = path + "/" + sname
    tname = (os.path.basename(vlocation)[0:28]+"_stack.tif")
    tfname = (os.path.basename(vlocation)[0:28]+"_stack")
    rlocation = path+ "/" +tname
    self.textEdit_3.setText(tname)
    if os.path.exists(vlocation):
        iface.addVectorLayer (vlocation,"","ogr")
    else:
        QMessageBox.about(self, "Error", "Invalid shape file location")
    if os.path.exists(rlocation):
        iface.addRasterLayer (rlocation,tfname,"gdal")
    else:
        QMessageBox.about(self, "Error", "Invalid raster file location")
```

Comment: Did you click or double-click on your `tableWidget` row ?

Comment: Move `self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.OpenQgis)` outside the loop otherwise you are attaching to the button multiple events. It causes your "only" click to emit multiple calls and hence add multiple layers. Could be wrong: untested

Comment: @ J. Monticolo  I clicked the row once and click the second button. Basically I have to select the row and click the second button to open the files.

Comment: @ThomasG77 Thank you! That definitely was the problem and I have been looking at the code for three days now. You can change it as an answer if you wish.

Comment: "Official" answer done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.OpenQgis)` outside the loop otherwise you are attaching to the button multiple events.

It causes your "only" click to emit multiple calls and hence add multiple layers.